# Obscure "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'."

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

I'm using LinqPad and LinqKit to try to learn more about linq to construct complex queries, but I seem to be stuck on simple queries.  I haven't found a solution to the error in the question description when I input the following -simple- expression:

```
QHPatients.AsExpandable().Where(p =>
    p.QHEncounters.Where(PredicateBuilder.True<QHEncounter>().Compile()).Any())
```

If I run the code in VS I get the following error instead: "System.InvalidOperationException : Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025"

Answer (score 0):

```
p.QHEncounters.Where(PredicateBuilder.True<QHEncounter>().Compile())
```

Without knowing the actual types you use, I guess you will need to either call `.AsExpandable()` on your `QHEncounters` or omit the `.Compile()` call.

Comment: I'm using Linq to SQL.  So QHPatient is an IQueryable and QHEncounters is an ICollection.

Comment: Did you try to drop the .Compile()?